What type of visa does he need to enter Greece?
My friend is traveling from Jordan to Canada with me. We will stop 6 hours in Greece for transit.During this time we would like to visit Athens.
He is a Jordanian citizen. We checked the website and found a few types of visas:

Transit visa
Tourist visa

Which one is the best in our case?

With the hassle and possibility of you missing the onward flight, or your transit time getting shorter due to delay in incoming flight, I suggest to skip the visit. Plan a proper trip.

I seriously doubt you have time to do this. You need to deplane, clear Immigration, collect your baggage, re-check your baggage for your onward flight, clear security, and get to your gate before it closes (30-60 mins before departure). You’d need 30-60mins to get to Athens city centre, depending on your mode of transport. Even if your baggage is checked through to Canada, you’d have a couple of hours at most of stressed time running around Athens hoping there’s no traffic issues that would delay your return to the airport

@Traveller it is not usually necessary to collect and re-check bags unless the two flights were bought separately.

@phoog Yes, I know, that’s why my comment mentions ‘baggage checked through’.  The OP doesn’t state whether they’re booked through or self-transferring (or will only have carry on bags).

To enter any of the Schengen countries you need a visit visa. That does include Greece.
This is however short the visit is, even if you only need to collect your luggage you need a full visit visa.
Transit visa only allow for staying in the international part of the airport for those who need them.

To avoid confusion, EU pages use the name airport transit visa. Other countries have more liberal transit visa, which may confuse people. So... one need a short stay visa also to transit from a ferry to the airport.

@GiacomoCatenazzi not only to avoid confusion but also because there was formerly a type B "transit visa" that more closely resembled the "traditional" transit visa, as it was for travelers who were planning to clear Schengen entry controls for the purpose of transit.  I presume that experience showed the distinction between this and a regular "short stay" to be unimportant in practice and that this is the reason for their having abolished type B visas.  Such travelers have needed a type C short-stay visa ever since.
